# How to create the only copy of "object" and test it

Tags: c, linux

So I am writing a program for BT RFCOMM in linux in C. There can only be one socket connecting to bluetooth hardware, so I thought of having private File Descriptor to the socket. So initialising RFCOMM updates local source file variable:

source_file.c

```
static int fd;

int rcomm_init()
{
    fd = socket();
}
```

so by doing this there can only be one connection to bluetooth socket. But I have no way of unit testing this.

I was wondering if anyone knows a better way of creating "something" that can only be one and able to test it?

Comment: Does your real `rcomm_init` function contain checks to handle if its called multiple times? If it does, what does the function return then? If it returns an "error", then you can simply test that: The function returns okay the first call, and an error the second call. Another test might be to copy the functionality of `rcomm_init` to create a connection, and then call `rcomm_init` to make sure it returns with an error. In both cases you should of course verify that the error code is what's expected for each case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create only one single object, you need the Singleton design pattern.

Some generalities can be found here: [Wiki page on Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but there are plenty more web pages on design patterns and singletons in particular.

Comment: I have been looking into singletons, but they are more of OOP concept and could not find anything about C singletons.